# Can I encrypt the OS for boot only?

Tags: boot, security, encryption

I have a LAMP system running (of an SD card on small computer) that monitors some arbitrary data. I return the data as JSON from the page so that it can be used in whatever reason its fit for.

I would like to protect the PHP SOurce files and other code from prying eyes. I know that the root and user password MUST be very strong to prevent brute or lucky entry.

How would I prevent users from accessing any data within the Linux OS (/usr; /etc) when they take the SD card out and try and mount it or extract it on another system?

-EDIT

I [found this](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html) for FreeBSD how can I configure it for Ubuntu?

Comment: I would use LUKS, or use an actual server with a real hard disk.

Comment: What benefit does a real hard disk give me?

Comment: Harder to get at physically... Want to come down to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way and most difficult for any intruder is to use LVM and a separate USB key to store the key data for auto decryption.

This answer is very close to what I have asked

https://askubuntu.com/a/90911/37108

But there are other ways to achieve what I need without a separate USB key but pointed out that it is very easy to hijack grub and boot into root with full access.