# Unencrypting a hard drive

Tags: 13.04, login, encryption

I've mistankenly checked the 'encrypting hard drive' box during installation of 13.04. As a result every time I turn the laptop on,  it asks for a password before I get to the users login screen. I would like to get rid of that first password and as it turned out I will have to revert the encryption of the hard drive. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

While my solution won't remove the disk encryption (I'm pretty sure you have to do a block copy of your unencrypted version over your encrypted disk to do that), you can make your system decrypt itself at boot time.

The process documented in 
[How to configure LVM & LUKS to autodecrypt partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition) should be of use to work around this issue. When your system boots, it will find the key and decrypt the drive (instead of prompting for a password).

Comment: Cheers, Andrew. I'll give it a go and let you know.